# How to use "qualified"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Suppose there is an honorable contest. This contest is organised into different levels. There is a regional level and then is the national level.

Suppose I had contended in the first level and secured success in it. Then I am eligible in the next level.

I have to articulate this in a word both formally or colloquially. I need help to do it.

> 1. I have qualified the first round
> 2. I have been qualified for the second round

Which one of the above is the right usage? New parallel words are also allowed.
If the second sentence is correct, how do I formulate the second one?

Comment: "I have qualified **in** the first round." (insert **in**); "I have xbeenx qualified for the second round." (delete **been**) -- Both are correct. After that, please visit [ell.se]

Comment: You are **eligible to compete** in a competition, which means you have the necessary requirements to participate in a tournament.

Comment: Colloquially, you can say, "I made it past the first round.  I get to [move on/advance] to the second round."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first sentence can be written as "I was qualified in the first round" and the second can be "I am qualified for the second round"...both usage are correct

Comment: It is not helpful to give inaccurate answers.

Comment: The first sentence can be written as "I (have) qualified in the first round" and the second as "I (have) qualified for the second round"... both these usages are correct.